# How to use the below symbol in itemize using enumitem? (right arrow tip)

Tags: symbols, itemize, enumitem

To change the bullet point to diamond, I can do it using the `enumitem` package as

```
\begin{itemize}[label={$\diamond$}]
```

Similarly, how can I get any of the below symbols (tip of a right arrow)? What is the keyword for this symbol?
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `pifont` package offers the symbols shown in your question. You can use the as follows:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}[label={\ding{226}}]
\item text item
\end{itemize}

\begin{itemize}[label={\ding{227}}]
\item text item
\end{itemize}

\begin{itemize}[label={\ding{228}}]
\item text item
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```